# Algorithmically produce all cube unwrapping

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, 3d

Suppose you have a cube.

How many ways can I unwrap this cube flat while requiring each face to have at least one edge attached to its original edge? And how can find all the possible unwraps?

Here's an example of a cube unwrapping:
[image]

Comment: This is equivalent to finding/listing the spanning trees of the octahedral graph (the 1-skeleton of octahedron, the dual polyhedron of cube). According to this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1321713/59379), the octahedral graph has $384$ spanning trees. There are algorithms to generate all spanning trees of a graph but unfortunately I don't understand any of them ;-p